# How to click the close image in a modal window using Junit in selenium

Tags: selenium

I am converting the Selenium IDE code to Selenium webdriver. I am using Junit and I am very new to Junit and chromedriver.I am trying to click and close the (x) image in a modal window and tried the following line of code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'//baseUrl/Images/Icons/16x16/close.png')]"));
```

The element has img class, title and src.

Could somebody help to fix this line of code to close the modal window.
Thanks

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML. What happens when you run that code?

Answer (score 0):

Simply using .click()

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'//baseUrl/Images/Icons/16x16/close.png')]")).click();
```

Also, I am not sure about the syntax for JUnit. I have used selenium web driver with Python only so the syntax might be different. But the click() method is what you are really looking for.

Comment: Hello , I was able to use the below command to close the modal window  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#ModalDialog img.modalClose")).click();  but , it works when i put a breakpoint and run in debug mode. It is not working in normal mode or when a breakpoint is not given in the debug mode. Could anybody suggest  ways to make it work in the normal mode ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might want to get the xpath of close button and use click() method on it.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'//baseUrl/Images/Icons/16x16/close.png')")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it's a timing issue. Just add a wait so that the dialog has a chance to be displayed and then click it.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div#ModalDialog img.modalClose"))).click();
```

Comment: Thank you Jeff. I added the wait and the code is working now. Thanks for helping out. - Kalaivani

Comment: If this answered your question, please accept it as the answer.